# Sent from one Other World to another. Another encounter in the same turn?

Tags: arkham-horror

One of my characters was in The Abyss and had an encounter there, which stated to attempt a luck+1 skill check, which ended up sending my investigator to The Dreamlands. Do I get to immediately have another Other World encounter for The Dreamlands in the same turn, or is this only when the card specifically mentions "..and have an encounter there"? Also, does this sudden shift between Other Worlds mean that my investigator gets delayed, or is this also only if the card specifically says so?

Answer (score 6):

Your character moves to the Dreamlands, no further encounter that turn.

As the card says "Move to the Dreamlands" the character is not delayed.  If it had said something like "A Gate Opens and pulls you to the Dreamlands" then the character would have been delayed.

Comment: But "a gate opens" only happens in Arkham, not in Other World locations, right?

Comment: @Jefromi - That's certainly the general case, and the "Gate Opens" rule is within the Arkham Encounter section of the rulebook.  On the other hand, I'm not examining the hundreds of gate cards to see if that phrase appears there or not :)